# How to get data form an array in a method

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, jcombobox

I'm creating a project using java, but i have an error.  I have created a method to generate some results to an array, but when i use it i don't get the results that I'm looking for.  Please help me on this, here is my code.

```
public static String[] getYear(){
    String[] w = new String[6];


    int z = 0;
    for(int x = 7;x<7;x++)
    {
      w[z] = String.valueOf(x);

      z = z++;
    }
    return w;
```

This is how my `combobox` code looks:

```
com_year.addItem(form_student.getYear());
```

When I'm using it in a `combobox` the result I get is this:

`[Ljava.lang.String;@1073463`

But I need to get this:

```
1

2

3

4

5

6
```

Can u please help me on this.

Comment: use arraylist so you dont get all the problems with arrays

Comment: i changed it to this but i still get the same result              public static String[] getYear(){
        String[] w = new String[6];
        
         
        int z = 0;
        for(int x =0;x<w.length;x++)
        {
          w[z] = String.valueOf(x);
          
          z = z++;
        }
        return w;
        
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You for loop condition is incorrect. This

```
for(int x = 7;x<7;x++)
```

Starts at 7 which is not less than 7 so the loop never runs.

I think you wanted

```
for (int x = 0; x < w.length; x++)
```

Also, your output is the default `toString()` from Object (Array doesn't override it). You can use `Arrays.toString(arr)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the line `for(int x = 7; x < 7; x++)`.  It reads that `x = 7`, which isn't less than 7, so it skips over the whole for loop.  Try replacing `x = 7` with `x = 1`.

Also, instead of displaying the string (that's where your're getting the weird numbers and symbols), you need to be displaying the string's contents.  Try something like

```
for (int myInteger : q)
{
    System.out.println(myInteger);
}
```

Comment: Please remember to format code (and *code only*) properly as code by using either 4 spaces in the beginning (question/answer/full line) or between the `` (part of a line) symbols. It provides more readability and makes a post look better ;) (As for this answer, I just editted for that, just remember in the future)